# When clicking an 'a' element, my script is not catching transition

Tags: php, jquery

In my site for every page, I included javascript code which is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").click(function () {
        var adress = $(this).attr("href");
        $.post("changeURL.php", {
            send: adress
        });
    });
});
```

I want to catch the transition to another pages, when user clicks on each link in the page. And redirect to one certain page with parameter is clicked address. *For example*:

```
  In one of pages, I have address of the google, which is google.com. And when user
clicks on this address, we will redirect on certain page with get parameter 
address=google.com.
  This included javascript code is redirect to the certain page when clicked links.
```

Our certain page is 'changeURL.php'. This page receives sent address, change it and then redirect to the parser. For example:

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['send'])){
     $site_name = $_POST['send']."?from=mysite.localhost";
     header("parser.php/?parsingThisSite=".$site_name);
     exit();    
   }
?>
```

But this code is not working, I checked code of *changeURL.php* [replacing page code on this]:

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['send'])){
     echo "<script>alert('hello')</script>";  
   }
?>
```

But it is not alerting.
if I check javascript code, it works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").click(function () {
        alert("You want to go!");
    });
});
```

What I'm doing wrong? why after clicking it isn't gone to the 'changeURL.php', and goes straight on link in href attribute.
P.S: My webserver is USBWebServer, jQuery version is 1.10.2

Comment: Are you trying to remove something, or redirect users? Is anything alerting?

Comment: Check the console, whats it say?

Comment: Also someone downvoted you, probably because your question isnt a question. You might want to edit your post a bit.

Comment: Why not using the `done` callback of `$.post`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it intend to remove something? This code will send your link address to server and if you intend to prevent redirect, on click of anchor add one of the following at the end of your click event

```
$('a').click(function() {
   // your code
   return false;
});
```

or

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
   // your code
   event.preventDefault();
});
```